# Is there a possibility to keep settings in Android app release configuration deployment by Visual Studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio, settings, release

In Visual Studio when I deploy an Android app in debug configuration, settings (and data) of the app are kept. Is there a possibility to keep settings in release configuration deployment, also?

I tried it by adb, but that seems quite complicated.